# Comprehesive support for graphviz (linting/autocompletion/snippets)

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-system, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-syntastic, snippets

Vim comes with some support (syntax highlighting) out of the box for the DOT language (graphviz)

In addition, I found the plugin: https://github.com/wannesm/wmgraphviz.vim, which provides integrated compilation and interactive viewing. Furthermore, this is the only plugin that I could find providing graphviz support.

I am coding up a complicated graph and ideally, I'd like to have a bit more advanced support, particularly **linting, autocompletion  and snippets**.

Is anyone aware of tools that do this?